# How to generate client password from salt

Tags: mysql, encryption

I got a PLC which can't use any of the MySql connector's. So I want to build my own very simple connector, just to insert values directly into MySql.

When connection to MySQL I get a salt string like "HZo?+WV-w5>ygxH;1%`6" and I have the user password "password". How do I compute the password in the connection response ?

[image: Here is a sample from wireshark]

Comment: Beware. **None** of MySQL's built in functions are suitable for hashing passwords. Even its own documentation for the `PASSWORD()` function says, *"you should not use it in your own applications."* Then it goes on to suggest using MD5 or SHA2 instead. This is **bad advice**. MD5 is already broken, and SHA2 is unsuitable because it is too computationally light. A much better solution is to use [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: I know that MD5 i broken, but that is not my question. I want to login to MySql as client. I get a greeting from MySQL and in that telegram is a SALT that i have to use together with the user credientals to make the password reply. I don't know how to calculate the password. What algorythm to use. Thats my problem.